# Deleted empty partition via Disks, which hid others. According to gParted those parts still exist. Help?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, 16.04, gparted

[**IMG1 | Disks - parts**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqX5L.png)

[**IMG2 | gParted - parts**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51wfi.png)

After I attempted to delete an unused partition I created with hopes of using it for SteamOS game-space. Disks now shows I only have 2 partitions, BUT gParted says "No no, you're good man."

I attempted to run Ubuntu&SteamOS in recov mode, running a couple standard procedures offered by those modes.

Could someone help me understand what this traitor "Disks" has done with the parts??

Comment: From the GParted screen shot I assume that the partition you deleted freed up ~78 GiB of space between logical partitions sda7 and sda8.  This makes it easy to grow sda7 to use the extra space.  If you need to grow sda8, then that requires first moving the partition to left, then growing the partition which is a lengthy process.  NOTE:  I highly **recommend backing up all your data before editing partitions** in case anything goes wrong due to a software bug, hardware failure, or power outage.

Comment: Curtis Gedak, thanks for your comment & advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@Curtis Gedak](https://askubuntu.com/users/76690/curtis-gedak) for your comment!

> From the GParted screen shot I assume that the partition you deleted
>   freed up ~78 GiB of space between logical partitions sda7 and sda8.
>   This makes it easy to grow sda7 to use the extra space. If you need to
>   grow sda8, then that requires first moving the partition to left, then
>   growing the partition which is a lengthy process. NOTE: I highly
>   recommend backing up all your data before editing partitions in case
>   anything goes wrong due to a software bug, hardware failure, or power
>   outage. – [Curtis Gedak](https://askubuntu.com/users/76690/curtis-gedak)